# Flatten dynamic Object using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following:

```java
@Data
public class LLMAsset {
  public Object inputs = null;
  public Object outputs = null;
}
```

inputs and outputs can be any type of Object. For example:

```json
inputs: { 
  name: "user",
  age: {
    number: 12
  } 
}
```

or it might be just:

```json
inputs: "some string"
```

So it depends on the user input. If it's a nested object i would like to flatten it. I've seen there's the Jackson `@JsonUnwrapped` but it doesn't seem to work. I assume because I use an Object? How can i solve this?

The user logs some type of asset which can have dynamic input and output field. I would like to index only the input and output fields and flatten them.

This is my current solution which works but it feels like dirty code. might be a better option?

```java
public class Asset {

  private Integer version;
  private String category;
  public Object input = null;
  public Object output = null;

  public Asset() {}

  public Asset(Object input, Object output) {
    this.input = input;
    this.output = output;
  }

  public Map<String, String> flattenIndexedFields() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {
      addKeys(
        "",
        JsonResolver.objectMapper.readTree(
          JsonResolver.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(getFieldsToIndex())
        ),
        map
      );
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return map;
  }

  private ObjectNode getFieldsToIndex() {
    ObjectNode inputsOutputObj = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
    inputsOutputObj.set(
      "chain_inputs",
      objectMapper.valueToTree(this.getChain_inputs())
    );
    inputsOutputObj.set(
      "chain_outputs",
      objectMapper.valueToTree(this.getChain_outputs())
    );
    return inputsOutputObj;
  }

  private void addKeys(
    String currentPath,
    JsonNode jsonNode,
    Map<String, String> map
  ) {
    if (jsonNode.isObject()) {
      ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
      Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> iter = objectNode.fields();
      String pathPrefix = currentPath.isEmpty() ? "" : currentPath + ".";

      while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = iter.next();
        addKeys(pathPrefix + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), map);
      }
    } else if (jsonNode.isArray()) {
      ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) jsonNode;
      for (int i = 0; i < arrayNode.size(); i++) {
        addKeys(currentPath + "[" + i + "]", arrayNode.get(i), map);
      }
    } else if (jsonNode.isValueNode()) {
      ValueNode valueNode = (ValueNode) jsonNode;
      map.put(currentPath, valueNode.asText());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Using a proper JSON parser should already take care of this: the JSON structure can't have "any type of object" because JSON only models the plain (unclassed) JS object. You parse your JSON, then you query the result for key/value pairs, and values can be a boolean, number, string, array, the `null` object, or a generic key/value pair object. That's it, that's the only six options you get. Ask for a key, check what type it is, then do whatever you need to do based on that type. But if you don't know what your input is, how would you know what to do with it?

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear but basically if it's array/nested object i would like to flatten it when i writeValueAsString. so  { age: { number: 12 } } would be { age.number : 12 }. From my understanding @JsonUnwrapped does that for me

Comment: Then give [the documentation for that annotation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html)  a quick read, because that's not what it does. It'll turn `{ age: { number: 12 } }` into `{ number: 12 }`. But perhaps importantly: can you update your question with _why_ you need the data transformed in this way? Because that transformation might not be the best way to achieve what you _actually_ need.

Comment: I've updated the question with some explanation. Would love to hear if you have recommendation to improve this code. I'm thinking of putting all the flatting logic in another class. What do you think? I'm pretty new to Java :)

Comment: Don't put an "edit" in your post: future visitors, and future potential "answerers" don't care. Your post should just one cohesive post giving all the details so that people can tell whether your problem is their problem, too =) If you update your post with additonal details, work those into your post as if they were there from the start. If people need to know about the edit history, they can click the edit history link. And if you're pasting code, please use modern triple-ticks with the language indicator (github style) rather than four-spaced indented. Condensed code means fewer scrollbars.

Comment: That said, if your "current solution" doesn't actually solve the problem, remember to say what it's doing, and how that differs from what you expected. You can't just add your current code to the end of your post and leave it at that: does it work? Because if so, problem solved. Does it _not_ work? Talk about that.

Comment: wow thank you for the info! :D 
my current solution solves the issue but i'm not sure if what i did is good practice